# Using pushjack in a flask API to send Apple Push Notifications (APNS)

Tags: python, ios, flask, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use [pushjack](http://pushjack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-pushjack.apns) within my flask API in order to send push notifications to my iOS app.

How do I specify the passphrase for the certificate file? The initialisation of the `APNSSandxoxClient` doesn't have a parameter to pass it on?

According to the docs: it's like this:

```
APNSSandboxClient(certificate, default_error_timeout=10, default_expiration_offset=2592000, default_batch_size=100)
```

Comment: OK. As a workaround how can I remove the passphrase from certificate .pem file?

Comment: This [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/515833/how-to-remove-private-key-password-from-pkcs12-container) answers the second question...